# Adding to the previous state of an object property inside of Redux Reducer

Tags: reactjs, object, redux

The title of this is probably not the best, but I'm just simply trying to create a simple budget app where you can add your income for the month, and subtract or add to the state of the budget based off - well whatever you decide you want your budget to be. The problem I'm having is the object I created to hold the budget, only updates the amount with whatever the last number was entered instead of adding or subtracting to it. Here is my reducer and action (they are not in the same file in the project), I realize I'm probably missing something rather simple but I appreciate any help I can get.

```
const budgetReducerDefaultState = {budget: 0};
export default (state = budgetReducerDefaultState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_INCOME':
            return { budget: state.budget =+ action.income }

        default:
            return state; 
    }
};

////Action

export const addIncome = (income) => ({
    type: 'ADD_INCOME',
    income
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have an extra `=` in your reducer at `state.budget =+ action.income`. It should just be `state.budget + action.income`. It is instead reassigning the value of `state.budget` to `action.income` instead of adding them together.

Comment: Well, that is embarassing. Thanks so much, that definitely solved it!

Comment: No need to be embarrassed! It happens to all of us. Glad I could help.